# LDAP filter string for Active Directory Users and Computers "find" dialogue

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

In Active Directory Users and Computers (ADUC), users can right-click an OU and select "Find" to search from all objects in the OU. On the first tab the user is presented with a "Name" and "Description" field to use for simple queries. However, the Name field appears to search against multiple fields in AD, such as canonicalName, sAMAccountName, and distinguishedName. I have not been able to find any documentation on MSDN that outlines a complete list of fields used when searching ADUC this way.

I am now writing a C# application, where one of the requirements is to search AD for an object. Since it it parsing user input, and different users favor different identifiers, the name of the object may be anything that would return the object using the find dialogue of ADUC. I am using a System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher to achieve this, but I cannot seem to replicate the exact search behavior of ADUC.

Exactly which fields does the Name field of the ADUC "Find" dialogue query against, and what is the equivalent LDAP filter string?

Comment: I don't knwo what the filter is, but there is this tool which seems to allow you to monitor what is requested to an Active Directory : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897539 . You could try to monitor what is the search filter of these requests

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me, and provided an awesome tool for the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Esteban's suggestion, I ran the [AdInsight utility](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897539) provided by Sysinternal and pulled this filter string:

(&(&(|(&(objectCategory=person)(objectSid=*)(!samAccountType:1.2.840.113556.1.4.804:=3))(&(objectCategory=person)(!objectSid=*))(&(objectCategory=group)(groupType:1.2.840.113556.1.4.804:=14)))(anr=MyObjectID*)))

However, if you aren't concerned about types and are willing to see ALL objects, this appears to still work:

(&(anr=MyObjectID*))